# Windows task scheduler will run only when I right click and run the file

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .py file which need to be scheduled every day. I have scheduled it and did everything as stated in this link https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler. But after all is done, my file still wont run unless i open the task scheduler and run the file by right clicking the particular task.

Can I know why?

Comment: What do your triggers look like?

Comment: Did you set it to be run as your user?  Do you turn your machine go to sleep at night?